# UPDATE table with PL/SQL trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have this trigger, and I am getting an arror message when I run it; "bad bind variable".
I can't seem to see where the problem lies. Any help would be appreciated.

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_placed AFTER UPDATE
OF STATUS_ID  ON STATUS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.STATUS_ID = 7 
  THEN
     UPDATE STUDENT
        SET PLACED_Y_N = 'Y'
      WHERE RECORD_NUMBER = :NEW.record_number;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Show full message `bad bind variable ....`.

Comment: Error(7,17): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NAME'

Comment: It is not exact message that you have.

Comment: im using sql developer and thats all im getting

Comment: Do you have column "record_number" in table "STATUS"?

Comment: You are facing that error simply because you are trying to reference column with `:new` qualifier that is not present in a table a trigger is defined on. In your situation it can be either `status_id` or `record_number`, or  maybe even both. So make sure that the `status` table has those columns.

Comment: The trigger code you've shown doesn't reference `:new.name`, so the error doesn't seem to match. Do you have a script with multiple commands?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_placed AFTER UPDATE

OF STATUS_ID  ON STATUS

REFERENCING OLD AS o NEW AS n

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   IF n.STATUS_ID = 7 

   THEN

      UPDATE STUDENT

      SET PLACED_Y_N = 'Y'

      WHERE RECORD_NUMBER = n.record_number;

  END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use lowercase for Oracle objects, you'll have to surround object names with quotes (") and match the case exactly to get it to work.

like this

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_placed AFTER UPDATE
 OF STATUS_ID  ON STATUS
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :new.STATUS_ID = 7 
THEN
 UPDATE STUDENT
    SET PLACED_Y_N = 'Y'
  WHERE RECORD_NUMBER = :NEW."record_number"; --quotes (") required for column name.
END IF;
END;
```